# Evaluate function inside lambda on Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following structure on LISP

```
(setf *books* '(
        (  
            (:tit 'Titulo1)
            (:aut (quote Autor1) )
            (:gen 'Genero1)
            (:score 99)
        ) 
        (  
            (:tit 'Titulo2)
            (:aut (quote Autor2) )
            (:gen 'Genero2)
            (:score 40)
        ) 
))
```

Now, I want to reset all scores to zero, using `mapcar` and `lambda`. I try

```
(
    defun reset(list)
        (mapcar 
            (lambda(libro) 
               '(
                    (:tit (assoc :puntuacion libro))
                    (:aut (assoc :aut libro) )
                    (:gen (assoc :gen libro))
                    (:score 0)
                )
            ) 
            list
        )
)
```

The point is that `assoc` is not being evaluated inside the `lambda` function. How can I access the initial object?

Comment: Just to be sure- do you want to destructively modify `*books*`, or do you want to create a brand new object with all scores set to 0?

Comment: @MartinPůda, Actually, I'm learning LISP. I think both approaches could be useful for me to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quoting your code, so the following:

```
'((:tit (assoc :puntuacion libro))
  (:aut (assoc :aut libro) )
  (:gen (assoc :gen libro))
  (:score 0))
```

... is not evaluated. It is a literal list that contains various symbols and numbers, including `assoc`. There are two options here:

1. Use the backquote/comma mechanism of Lisp: the backquote is like quote except that when the quoted data contains a comma the expression after the comma is evaluated. You can imagine a template where some parts are fixed and other variables:

   ```
   `((:tit ,(cdr (assoc :punctuacion libro))))
     ...)
   ```

   Here above, the whole tree is quoted, except for the part that follows the comma. Note that you need to use `cdr` on the result of `assoc` to obtain the value, because `assoc` returns the entire entry, in other words the `(key . value)` couple.
2. Only shadow the part of the value that changes:

   ```
    (acons :score 0 libro)
   ```

   This is a purely functional approach where the `:score` of zero is appended in front of the association list. The resulting structure is for example:

   ```
    ((:score . 0)
     (:tit . 'Titulo1)
     (:aut . 'Autor1 )
     (:gen . 'Genero1)
     (:score . 99))
   ```

   The next time you ask for the `:score` with `assoc`, the first occurrence is obtained. If you are worried about having too many updates, you can also call `remove`:

   ```
    (acons :score 0 (remove :score libro :key #'car))
   ```

   Note that `remove` is purely functional too, a new list is built with some element removed (a destructive version would use `delete` but in your case that would be wrong since your code, by quoting a list, is using literal values which are not allowed to be modified by the standard). I would advise against using destructive operations at first.

   The above approach that call `acons` allows you to add keys to your data structure without worrying about breaking existing code elsewhere. For example, later you can add an `:iban` key without having to rewrite the code that updates `:score`.

### Remarks

- Please use readable names, like `:title` or `:author`
- Please format your code in a more conventional Lisp way
- Be careful about how your data is organized:

  ```
    (:score 40)
  ```

  The above is an association list from `:score` to the singleton list `(40)`. If you write instead `(acons :score 40 nil)` to build a proper association list, you will notice that this is printed as follows:

  ```
    ((:score . 40))
  ```

  This is a list having a single entry, which is:

  ```
    (:score . 40)
  ```

  The above is how a cons-cell whose `cdr` is *not a list* is printed. Generally speaking you want to call `(cdr (assoc ...))` to obtain the value, but if you don't like having this dot in your data, then you have to take into account that your value, `(cdr (assoc ...))`, is a list: so if you have a convention that this value is always a list of a single element, then you have to call `(car (cdr (assoc ...)))` instead, also known as `(cadr (assoc ...))`.